# Error 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

When I deploy a project in `Apache Tomcat 6.0` it's working fine. 
When I deploy the same project in `weblogic server 10.3` it's showing an error like below:

> Error 500--Internal Server Error
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   [HTTP:101249][weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@ae43b8 -
>   appName: '_appsdir_ab_dir', name: 'ab', context-path: '/ab',
>   spec-version: 'null']: Servlet class FirstServlet for servlet
>   FirstServlet could not be loaded because the requested class was not
>   found in the classpath . java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   FirstServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've built the code using JDK 7, but you're trying to run it on a Java 6 virtual machine. You'll need to *either* build it targeting JDK 6 *or* run it using Java 7.

Comment: how did you get that hint? I mean whats there in the stack trace to indicate this?